# Didn't recognise Material import in child modules angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have app.module.ts how to import a custom material.ts modules and I cant use material in components declared in module root. But when I create a child module(ClientModule) and declare a component here material cant be recognised.

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavigatorComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`ClientRegistrationComponent` does not work angular material, should I import material module too?

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ClientRegistrationComponent } from './client-registration/client-registration.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ClientRegistrationComponent]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

Comment: Please add more detail , which module did not work and post the code related

Comment: Sorry, code added :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use MaterialModule across your application, i would recommend you to create a SharedModule and import the SharedModule in all Modules.

If you do not want SharedModule, yes in the above case you need to import

Comment: Well, when i import my material module in app module (root). Should not all other components be able to use?

Comment: No only the components within the module can be used